# PhpStorm synchronise settings company wide

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, code-organization

I'm currently try to establish company wide coding standards and different setting which should be the same on every developers setup.

There are multiple way to achive this and the current aproach to sync some of the .idea-folders files via version control doesn't seems to be as easy as expected.

We also tried to use the 'Settings Repository' plugin which ended up in confusion.

Has anyone tried solve a similar problem? Does anyone use the plugin successful in a bigger team?

Would be happy to get some of your thoughts on this.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

With the recent release of PhpStorm 2017.2 it's now possible to apply code style from ESLint.

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/

> Import from ESLint
>
> You can now import some ESLint code style rules to the IDE’s
>   JavaScript code style settings. Reply ‘Yes’ when prompted about this
>   in the .eslintrc file to apply the matched rules and make the IDE
>   formatting more consistent with your ESLint configuration.

That's still not completely automatic, but maybe better than having the .idea folders in the repo.

Comment: we also using a plugin for some basic editor configurations. but first) we mainly have php files and second) you cant sync server settings by this approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Admin in your company setups personal Settings Repository (Upsteam).
   Configures code styles schemes.
2. Developer in your company adds this repository as "read-only source" (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-repository.html)

Currently, sometimes read-only source changes are not synced automatically, in this case please use `VCS` -> `Sync Settings` -> `Merge`.

Comment: Wenalso tried this but it looks like that not every change makes his way through the read-only repositories into PhpStorm. Which settings do you sync via this plugin? Do you also have issues with it?

Comment: There is no real issue. We just dont find any good documentation for this plugin. How exactly is your workflow?

Comment: @pennertenner Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172655 I am going to fix this issue in 2 weeks.